# How do I make all my main methods show execution time

Tags: java, inheritance, program-entry-point, abstract

It has been a while since I've programmed in Java and I just can't seem to solve it so I apologize in advance for anything stupid I might have done.

I am currently solving a list of math problems in Java. I create a new class called ProblemX for every problem. I want each class to print the duration time of the execution.
Rather than programming this in each seperate class I though I'd use some inheritance but that's where I got stuck.

```
Public abstract class Problem{

 public static void main(String[]args){
   Problem p = new Problem();
   long startTime = System.nanoTime();
   p.solve();
   long endTime = System.nanoTime();
   System.out.println("Execution time: " + (endTime - startTime) + " nanoseconds");
 }

abstract void solve();

}
```

This doesn't work because I can't create an instance of Problem in an abstract class.
I can't use a Solveable interface because then Problem has to define 'solve'.

Obviously I'm missing something here so if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can't `solve` measure and return the time it takes?

Comment: You can use `time java etc` on the command line to add timing.

Comment: @zapl Yes but if I try doing that in the super class it would just shift my problem to the solve method. Unless I do it in every child class but that would would take too much time.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know that and that would indeed be a solution but I'm just solving math problems in Eclipse, I'm not doing anything command line related and do not intend to make anything of my code, I'm only interested in the mathematical answer my code generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
public abstract void solve();

public void solveProblem() {
    startTime();
    solve();
    endTime();
    System.out.println(timeTaken);
}
```

Then just override solve and call solveProblem.

Comment: I can't call solveProblem unless I have a static main method or an instance of Problem.
The static main method won't work because then solveProblem and solve would have to be static (and overriding would be impossible)
 and I can't have an instance of problem because it is abstract.

Comment: Say you are writing a class Problem1 extends Problem. Override solve. In the main method create a new Problem1(); then call solveProblem()

Comment: That does exactly what I wanted! This isn't as complicated as I had expected. I guess I'll have to brush up on my Java a bit. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
public abstract class Problem{

    long startTime;

    long endTime;

    public void startTime(){
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    public void endTime(){
    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    public long measure(){
    return endTime - startTime;
    }

}

public class ProblemX extends Problem{

    public static void main(String[] a){
     ProblemX x = new ProblemX(); 
     x.startTime();
     //do your work
     x.endTime();
     System.out.println("time taken" + x.measure());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but seeing as I am going to make hundreds of these child problem classes I would still have to write that code in every one of those classes. I was hoping there would be a way to just implement the Problem class, write a solve() method and then get the execution time automatically. But if this isn't possible I'll use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
package com.stackoverflow;
public abstract class Problem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Problem p = new Problem(){

            @java.lang.Override
            protected void doCalculation() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Printing number... " + i);
                }
            }
        };
        p.solve();
        System.out.println("Execution time: " + p.getElapsedTime() + " nanoseconds");
    }

    private long startTime, endTime;
    private void doStartTime() {
        startTime = getSystemNanoTime();
    }
    private void doEndTime() {
        endTime = getSystemNanoTime();
    }
    private long getSystemNanoTime() {
        return System.nanoTime();
    }
    protected abstract void doCalculation();

    public void solve() {
        doStartTime();
        doCalculation();
        doEndTime();
    }
    public long getElapsedTime() {
        return endTime - startTime;
    }

}
```

lets say that you have a ProblemX class which overrides Problem. you should change the following rows in the static main method:

from:

Problem p = new Problem(){

```
@java.lang.Override
protected void doCalculation() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        System.out.println("Printing number... " + i);
    }
}
```

};

to:

```
Problem p = new XProblem();
```

Comment: This looks a lot like what I need! The only problem now is that my ProblemX class can't overwrite the doCalculation method anymore because it will always print all numbers from 1 to 1000.

Comment: Extended my original post with the changes you need to do to run XProblem code instead of my counter.